# UPS shipping error: "110000: XML Rating and Service Selection Service Unavailable"

Tags: ups, ups-api

It was working earlier today but now when I add a product and estimate shipping I get this error:

**110000: XML Rating and Service Selection Service Unavailable**

Only first one shipping applies or order and if select drop-down shipping then gets this error and shipping are still showing.

[image]